# Is there a notation for the distribution sampled from a set

Tags: probability, notation, uniform-distribution

Suppose we choose uniformly from the set S, is there a well accepted notation for this distribution? I imagine something like $X \sim U(S)$ or $X \sim Uniform(S)$? I want to use this to write that I choose iid random variables from a finite dimensional vector space, and it would be very compact to write $$X_1, X_2, ..., X_n\stackrel{iid}{\sim} U(\mathbf{F}_q)^n$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsolicited advice: I feel it is better/clearer writing style to write things out in plain words.

I think $U(S)$ or $\text{Uniform}(S)$ are well-understood *for finite sets $S$*, but I would still write "where $U(S)$ denotes the uniform distribution over the set $S$" nonetheless (after the first instance of the notation) to eliminate any ambiguity.

I would use the notation $X_1, \ldots, X_n \overset{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim} U(S)$ to denote i.i.d. samples from the aforementioned uniform distribution (do not use $U(S)^n$).

Comment: what's the meaning of $U(S)$ for an arbitrary $S$ ? It seems there's a theoretical gap between defining a uniform definition of $[0,1]$ and defining a uniform definition on a sphere (the Lebesgue measure of the latter is $0$).

Comment: distribution, not definition

Comment: @GabrielRomon I had finite sets in mind when I wrote the answer (given the OP's example of $\mathbb{F}_q$). I edited my answer to clarify. The typical construction of a uniform distribution on a sphere is taking a standard Gaussian vector and normalizing it to have unit length. More generally, I think a uniform distribution can be characterized using some phrasing like "proportional to area/volume" (e.g. for a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ you would use "probability of nice set is proportional to set's surface area", rather than Lebesgue measure). I am forgetting the rigorous way to go about this.

Comment: @GabrielRomon Good point, for example there is no such distribution as $U(\Bbb Q)$.